# Ransack : using nest with snake_case table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

My models are Menu, MenuDrink and Drink.

Association: Menu has_many Menudrinks, and has_many Drinks through MenuDrinks

MenuDrink table is an Intermediate table has drink's quantity column.

Data Example

- Menu1 coke:2/ diet coke:3/ water:5
- Menu2 coke:1/ diet coke:3/ water:2
- Menu3 coke:2/ diet coke:3/ water:3

I tried to search the menus have coke:2 (Menu 1 and 2 are applicable in the example.)

```
-----Menu.rb------
has_many :menu_drinks
has_many :drinks, through: :menu_drinks

-----MenuDrink.rb-----
belongs_to :menu
belongs_to :drink

-----Drink.rb-------
has_many :menu_drinks
has_many :menus, through: :menu_drinks

q = {
    "g" => {
        "0" => {
            "g" => {
                "c" => {
                    "0" => {
                        "a" => { "0" => { "name" => "menu_drinks_quantity" } },
                        "p" => "eq",
                        "v" => { "0" => { "value" => 2 } }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        "1" => {
            "g" => {
                "c" => {
                    "0" => {
                        "a" => { "0" => { "name" => "drinks_drink_name" } },
                        "p" => "eq",
                        "v" => { "0" => { "value" => "coke" } }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    "m" => "and"
}


Menu.ransack(q).result
=> Select "menu"...... 
    WHERE ("drinks"."drink_name" = 'coke' AND "menu_drinks_menus"."quantity" = 2)
```

The return was different from what I expected.

I think "menu_drinks"."number", not "**menu_drinks_menus**"."number" .

Why my code doesn't work?

really appreciate your support!

Comment: Add the actual code for the models (or at least the relavant portions). Code is always better than trying to descibe what the code does.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing either unless by quantity you mean volume. A menu does not usually have quatities of beverages - an Order does.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added models, so please take a look.

Comment: >I don't really understand what you are doing... You are right. My naming was wrong. The menu is a drink & beverage combo.

Comment: I had extra "}", so my code didn't work I expected. I figured it out what my problem is. I couldn't create a SQL  joins(:menu_drinks, :drinks).where(menu_drinks: {quantity:2}).where(drinks: {drink_name: 'coke'})  by using nest. I've tried to use grouping, but it doesn't work.